# Make Eclipse treat .h file as C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ganymede

All of our C++ headers use a .h extension. Eclipse thinks these are C headers and flags them with lots of syntax errors on things like classes and namespaces.

I've tried to change the file type association from:

```
Preferences > C/C++ > File types
```

but it's "locked".

Interestingly, "*.h" is associated with both C and C++ headers, but it seems to be using C.  How can I get Eclipse to treat .h files as C++?

Comment: A more language agnostic "how to change association" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850756/how-to-remove-the-lock-in-file-association-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new project and specify your source area as the location.  However, be sure you select C++ project (I usually use the makefile option).  This is all you should have to do in order to make the parser recognize C++ syntax.

Comment: Another factor is that all the source files are accessed through RSE.  I figured out how to import files to a project via RSE, and then this solution worked.  Thanks!

Comment: ... except that once I import them into a project, they seem to be local copies and don't sync via RSE anymore.  Rats.

Comment: Found the answer.  Instead of importing the files, link an RSE folder to the project.