# How to change the default C++ file extension in Eclipse CDT when creating a new file?

Tags: eclipse, filenames, eclipse-cdt

My team has been mandated to use a specific coding standard, and part of that standard is to use .cc as the suffix for C class implementation files (for sake of argument, it could have been .cxx, .c++, or any number of other suffixes which are not .cpp).

We're using the Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Toolkit) for development, however in the "New C++ Class" dialog, when you type in a class name as Classname, for example, it automatically names your Source file as Classname.cpp.

Sure, I could uncheck the "use default" checkbox and repair the suffix, but that's a few extra steps, and a lot to ask every Engineer on the large-ish project to remember to do each time they make a new C++ class.

I have been stumped, however, trying to find the option that allows one to specify the default suffix for C++ files in Eclipse CDT.  Any Eclipse gurus know this one off hand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Name Style > Files > C++ Source File > Suffix

Comment: Nice!  Was this feature present in Eclipse 3.6?  We're using Eclipse 3.7 with CDT 8.0 now, and I checked...sure enough, it was right where you said it was!

Comment: And just as an FYI...I just checked.  The feature is not present in Eclispe 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

I've digged Eclipse CDT code and found a solution:

append

```
nameStyle.cpp.source.suffix=.cc
```

to

```
<workspace location>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs
```

Here is how I did it:

1. ["Got started with CDT development"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development), checked out **org.eclipse.cdt.ui**
2. Opened **src/org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.wizards.filewizard/NewSourceFileGenerator.java** (actually I searched for the ".cpp" pattern and found it)
3. "public static String generateHeaderFileNameFromClass(String className)" tells us about **PreferenceConstants.NAME_STYLE_CPP_HEADER_PREFIX**
4. We jump to PreferenceConstants.java and obtain the IPreferencesService path: **nameStyle.cpp.source.prefix**
5. [This article](http://blog.balfes.net/2007/06/05/where-are-all-of-these-eclipse-preferences-stored/) nicely explains where the prefs are stored

Answer (score 2):

The bug mentioned by Ogre Psalm33 was fixed in 2013.

The location in Eclipse 4.4 is:

```
Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Name Style > Files
```

Related: [Make Eclipse treat .h file as C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226402/make-eclipse-treat-h-file-as-c)

Comment: Nice to see the 3.7 fix made it over to 4.x.  We're still on the 3.x line on my (very long duration) legacy project, but for up-to-date developers, this is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: it currently can't be done in Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) with CDT 7.0.0.  See [Eclipse Bugzilla entry](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=269772).  Apparently it's logged as a bug/missing feature, but nobody's assigned to work on it.