# How to set the C++ file extension to .cc in Eclipse for files created when starting a new project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, file-type

By default Eclipse (CDT) uses .cpp file extension for C++ files. I would like it to use .cc (and .hh) extensions instead but I cannot find such an option anywhere.

**edit:** To be precise, it creates a .cpp file when I start a new C++ project. Can this behaviour be changed to creating a .cc file?

I would have expected it under Window > Options > C/C++ > File Types, but as far as I can see that doesn't help. I've searched Google and the only page I found explains how to do it in Netbeans. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can follow the [instructions given here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801) to have a moderator merge your accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was wondering the same and just found this:

[How to change the default C++ file extension in Eclipse CDT when creating a new file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728531/how-to-change-the-default-c-class-suffix-in-eclipse-cdt)

Comment: Thanks! That is a very disappointing answer there :(

Comment: I have found a working solution, now check the link again

Answer (score 4):

The place to enter your extension is in Window → Preferences → General → C/C++ → File Types. Click the New button, enter your extension and select the file association.

Answer (score 3):

Look at Window->Preferences->General->Content Types
Browse to the Definition of a C++ Source File and add your file associations.

Comment: Sorry Tom, could you please be more specific? I don't see how this answer provides a solution.

Comment: In the content types pages you see a tree with all known content-types and their associated file-assocations. Search in that tree for the definition of C++ source files. If you select the entry you can add a certain file assocation (under the tree). There you can add two entries, '*.cc' and '*.hh'

Comment: Ok, thanks. These are already filled in. Doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It may be unrelated to the question but it solves my problem. I have files with *.ipp where my namespaces are defined. I can add *.ipp under the list of C++ source files. This forces eclipse to parse *.ipp files as C++ files. Previously these were treated as plain text files.